# Undefined index when index is defined

Tags: php, arrays, undefined

I am running into a problem with arrays and undefined indexes:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($response); $i++) {
$table .= "<tr>";

    for ($j = 0; $j < count($data); $j++) {
        $table .= "<td>".$response[$i][$data[$j]]."</td>";
    }   
}
```

So basically this section of my app builds tables based on user selected data.  The problem arises when outputting the  data.

In this case the $data array contains the following items:

id, first, last, transType, status, producer, prem, commissions

Now if I manually return $data[1] it kicks out "first" with no quotation marks.  So if I then manually return $response[0][first], it outputs the correct data.  But if I try to manually return:
 $response[0][$data[1]] 
I run into that undefined index notice.  However manually returning:
 $response[0][$data[0]] 
correctly outputs the id.

Does anyone have any idea what is going on?

Comment: `count($array)-1` maybe?  Or `foreach`.

Comment: Can I ask why you don't just use a simple foreach instead of a for loop?

Comment: @Derokorian Generally foreach is slower so if your array only contains only numbered indexes, it would be better to use for.

Comment: This is not true at all (at least in php) and runs into issues if your indexes are ever not perfectly ordered (IE 0, 1, 2, 4, 5... ) http://3v4l.org/6S0Bi

Comment: @ Derokorian , I hadn't really considered it.  Let me try the fix below and if it doesn't work I will try a foreach.  In this particular situation the indexes are perfectly ordered.

Answer (score 0):

PHP Undefined index notice usually fixes with this method :

```
if(isset(/* STH */)) // Do sth
```

So your code will become to this shape :

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($response); $i++) {
    $table .= "<tr>";
    for ($j = 0; $j < count($data); $j++) {
        if(isset($response[$i][$data[$j]]))
            $table .= "<td>".$response[$i][$data[$j]]."</td>";
    }
    $table .= "</tr>"; // Added this to close Table Row
}
```

Good Luck